# Google plus API depreciation

Tags: api, nginx, oauth, scope, google-plus

I am using https://github.com/agoragames/nginx-google-oauth for auth on my website. I received an email from Google saying that the `plus.me` scope of the Google Plus API is being deprecated. I don't see that referenced in the code. I am not sure about Libraries it may be using.

Can someone confirm this is going to continue working after the shutdown?

Comment: This code is almost 5 years old. Google announced they were pulling the plug on Google Plus sometime last year and they are shutting it down for good on April 2. They have already started incrementally shutting it down as of last week and the API will be completely inoperable on March 7. See: https://developers.google.com/+/

Comment: If you've ever wanted to get involved with open source code maintenance this might be a great opportunity to make some changes to the API connectors and commit some fresh and functional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this line in the code](https://github.com/agoragames/nginx-google-oauth/blob/c01b23083b600701fb1e13972044768e5cbf6dcb/access.lua#L73), it is making its call directly to Google's OAuth endpoint, and then [later](https://github.com/agoragames/nginx-google-oauth/blob/c01b23083b600701fb1e13972044768e5cbf6dcb/access.lua#L122) making a call to Google's userinfo v2 endpoint. In neither place does it use a plus scope nor a plus API (although its claim that it's asking for "ALL" scopes looks wrong).

The Google+ API and Scope shutdown does not appear to be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Today (7th March, 19) Google+ API shut down completely, I had issue in rails application with authentication and I solved it by replacing OpenIdConnect endpoint, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043208/10522579)